# Creating an Outlook reminder on a Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, outlook

I want to create an Outlook reminder from Excel using Excel VBA on Mac.

There is an Outlook library for VBA but this is not the case for Excel on Mac. Can I import the library manually?

Probably this is not possible. Is there is a workaround?

I can activate the Outlook Application via Script, but after that, I can't reference the App even if I create an Object like this:

```
Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific library for the Mac OS which you could import and use. But you can use AppleScript for automating Office applications on the Mac. In fact, VBA makes heavy use of AppleScript's capabilities.

On Windows the COM technology is used for automating Office applications. It doesn't exist on the Mac OS, so your choice would be AppleScript. For example, if you want to automate Mac Office apps from external code, Applescript is one option. You can also call AppleScript from your VBA, see [Run an AppleScript with VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask) for more information.